# Xml Unmarshalling leads to junk characters in golang

Tags: xml, go, parsing, struct, xml-parsing

I am new to Golang and XML too.
i need to open an XML file and do some changes with XML parsing and sent the resultant XML back to the HTTP response(postman).

For XML parsing needed to convert the opened byte value to the struct model using

```
xmlFile,err := os.Open("sample.xml")
byteValue ,_:= ioutil.ReadAll(xmlfile)
var model structModel
xml.Unmarshal(byteValue,&model)
```

but while converting the struct back to byteArray after changes , using xml.Marshal as
byteValue,_=xml.Marshal(model)

It adds unwanted junk character along with the resultant xml field data "&#xA"
This is found as a new line character used in xml
so tried removing the characters by replacing those with "\n" using bytes.Replace after marshalling

```
byteValue = bytes.Replace(byteValue,[]byte("&#xA;"),[]byte("\n"),-1)
```

The xml output shows fields differently after Unmashalling and Marshalling using struct
Example - vmap:VMAP and vmap:AdBreak filednames in sample.xml is changed to simply VMAP and AdBreak respectively in the resultant XML

The sample XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vmap:VMAP xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/vmap-1.0" version="1.0">
   <vmap:AdBreak User="u001" device="mobile">
      <Ad id="31966499.140094429862144" sequence="1">
         <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
      </Ad>
      <Ad id="24061566.140094429860608" sequence="3">
         <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
      </Ad>
   </vmap:AdBreak>
</vmap:VMAP>
```

The output we got as

```
    <VMAP vmap="data" version="1.0">                                   **[vmap:VMAP -> VMAP]**
       <AdBreak User="user_1" device="cellular">                  **[vmap:AdBreak ->AdBreak]**
           <Ad id="31966499.140094429862144" sequence="1">
               <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
           </Ad>
           <Ad id="24061566.140094429860608" sequence="3">
               <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
           </Ad>
       </AdBreak>
   </VMAP>
```

And the struct used for this operation is taken from this [tool](https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/)

the struct is

```
type VMAP struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"VMAP"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Vmap    string   `xml:"vmap,attr"`
    Version string   `xml:"version,attr"`
    AdBreak struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        User   string `xml:"User,attr"`
        Device string `xml:"device,attr"`
        Ad     []struct {
            Text     string `xml:",chardata"`
            ID       string `xml:"id,attr"`
            Sequence string `xml:"sequence,attr"`
            Duration string `xml:"Duration"`
        } `xml:"Ad"`
    } `xml:"AdBreak"`
}
```

Now pls help me to get the output in the same format as the sample input xml like the xml versions , and the vmap:VMAP and vmap:adBreak should not change from the given format.

Answer (score 0):

The "junk" characters are the data in between elements collected by the `,chardata` fields, i.e.

```golang
Text string `json:",chardata"`
```

If you don't want the in-between-data then drop the `,chardata` fields.

---

The handling of namespace prefixes isn't supported out of the box. See issue [#9519](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519).

You'll have to do a bit of work:

- To produce namespace-prefixed elements you'll need a custom [`xml.Marshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.17.3#Marshaler).

  ```golang
  type MyElem struct { /* ... */ }

  func (e MyElem) MarshalXML(e *xml.Encoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
      type T MyElem
      start.Name.Local = "my_prefix:" + start.Name.Local
      return e.EncodeElement(T(e), start)
  }
  ```
- To produce namespace-prefixed attributes you'll need a custom [`xml.MarshalerAttr`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.17.3#MarshalerAttr).

  ```golang
  type MyAttr string

  func (a MyAttr) MarshalXMLAttr(n xml.Name) (attr xml.Attr, err error) {
      attr.Name.Local = "my_prefix:" + n.Local
      attr.Value = string(a)
      return out, nil
  }
  ```

Try it on [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kzTqbce5jhy).